# Data Validation from another Google Sheet

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

There is a way to do a data validation between 2 different Google Sheet?

I mean, I have 2 different types of Sheets:
1 - Master with all the information
2 - Various Sheets where i import some data from the Master

Now, i use the IMPORTRANGE function where i link to these second types of sheets each time I must do the data validation, but it is very long to do every time.
There is a way to link directly to the unique Master Sheets (like a Database central)?

Answer (score 1):

data validation and conditional formatting across 2 different spreadsheets or sheets is possible if you wrap your reference/range into `INDIRECT`

Comment: Can you give me an example?